# How to handle visibilty of properties in an UserControl?

Tags: wpf, properties, user-controls, visibility

I try to create a custom "TimePicker" - UserControl and struggle a bit with the design of the code.

In the XAML of the UserControl I created a ComboBox, which binds to a `List<int> HoursList`-property. This will contain all numbers from 0-23. I want to create a `DependencyProperty Hour` to keep track of the selected ComboBox Item via Binding in an other XAML file later.

**TimePicker.xaml**

```xaml
<Grid>
    <!--Hours-->
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding HoursList,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            SelectedIndex="0" ItemStringFormat="{}{0:00}">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**TimePicker.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class TimePicker : UserControl
{
    private List<int> hoursList;
    public readonly List<int> HoursList
    {
        get 
        {
            if (this.hoursList == null)
                LoadHoursList();

            return hoursList; 
        }
    }

    public TimePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// will create a new List<int> and fill it from 0-23 (int) representing the hours 
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadHoursList()
    {
        this.hoursList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            this.HoursList.Add(i);
    }
}
```

If I use the Control now in another XAML-file, it will look like this:

**Test.xaml**

```xaml
<my:TimePicker Margin="2"  />
```

My problem is that I can acess the HoursList-Property here. But it should be used for loading up the default values in the control only. Access should be possible with a `DependencyProperty Hour` later..So I want to keep the HoursList hidden.

Here an example that I want to forbid:

```xaml
<my:TimePicker Margin="2" HoursList="" />
```

Maybe I did not understand the mechanics correctly..any advice is appricated!

Comment: As a note, your HoursList property declaration doesn't need more than this: `public List<int> HoursList { get; } = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).ToList();`

Comment: thanks for this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not declare a public property at all, but just assign the ComboBox's ItemsSource in code behind:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbHours" .../>
```

Code:

```
public TimePicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cbHours.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 24);
}
```

Comment: won't this break my "MVVM" approach?
this confuses me kinda often..to decide if I do these things in codebhind..

Comment: No, having or not having an internal property in a UserControl has nothing to do with MVVM. You may even decide to add the 24 hour items in XAML...

Comment: ok, I will remove the HoursList property and set the ItemsSource in codebehind!
thank you